# Removing element in array of a typealias Swift

Tags: swift

I'm experimenting with implementing a notification center in Swift

For a given typealias (I do NOT want to change this)

```
typealias Observer = (_ name: String, _ data: Any) -> Void
```

You can have an array of this:

```
var observers = [Observer]()
```

But then how can I remove any given observer name?

If I have an observer "myObs"

```
for i in 0..<observers.count {
            if observers[i].name == "myObs" {
                observers.remove(at: i)
                return
            }
        }
```

will not remove the element, since any observer does not have a property name.

I wanted to use a protocol conforming to AnyObject, but then I will need to store the name within the protocol as well as it being contained in the typealias.

I have some fundamental misunderstanding...but what is it?

Comment: You need a dictionary not array here

Comment: Your declaration is misleading and to boot Swift 2 legacy, the recommended syntax is `typealias Observer = (String, Any) -> Void`, the parameter labels are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use dictionary `[String: Observer]` like below:

```
typealias Observer = (_ name: String, _ data: Any) -> String
let obs: Observer = { (name, data) in
    return name
}
let obs1: Observer = { (name, data) in
    return name
}
var observers = [String: Observer]()
observers[obs("MyObs", "some data")] = obs
observers[obs1("MyObs1", "some data")] = obs1

print(observers)
observers["MyObs"] = nil
print(observers)
```

The output is:

```
"["MyObs": (Function), "MyObs1": (Function)]\n"
"["MyObs1": (Function)]\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Observer` is an alias of a function, so `name` is basically a parameter, you cannot do so.

```
typealias Observer = (_ name: String, _ data: Any) -> Void
var observers = [Observer]()

func observer1(_ name: String, _ data: Any) { }
func observer2(_ name: String, _ data: Any) { }
func observer3(_ name: String, _ data: Any) { }
func observer4(_ name: String, _ data: Any) { }

observers.append(observer1)
observers.append(observer2)
observers.append(observer3)
observers.append(observer4)

observers.forEach { (observer) in
    print(observer) // Just "()"
}
```